# Understanding WebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest, streamreader

I found this snippet of code [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqrfmAmgn3U) that allows you to log into a website and get the response from the logged in page. However, I'm having trouble understanding all the part of the code. I've tried my best to fill in whatever I understand so far. Hope you guys can fill in the blanks for me. Thanks

```
string nick = "mrbean";
string password = "12345";

//this is the query data that is getting posted by the website. 
//the query parameters 'nick' and 'password' must match the
//name of the form you're trying to log into. you can find the input names 
//by using firebug and inspecting the text field
string postData = "nick=" + nick + "&password=" + password;

// this puts the postData in a byte Array with a specific encoding
//Why must the data be in a byte array?
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

// this basically creates the login page of the site you want to log into
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.mrbeanandme.com/login/");

// im guessing these parameters need to be set but i dont why?
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

// this opens a stream for writing the post variables. 
// im not sure what a stream class does. need to do some reading into this.
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();

// you write the postData to the website and then close the connection?
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Close();

// this receives the response after the log in
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
stream = response.GetResponseStream();

// i guess you need a stream reader to read a stream?
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

// this outputs the code to console and terminates the program
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You're looking for the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Stream is a sequence of bytes.

In order to use text with a Stream, you need to convert it into a sequence of bytes.

This can be done manually with the Encoding classes or automatically with `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.  (which read and write strings to streams)

---

As stated in the [documentation for `GetRequestStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx),

> You must call the Stream.Close method to close the stream and release the connection for reuse. Failure to close the stream causes your application to run out of connections.

---

The Method and Content-* properties reflect the underlying [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

Comment: Hi SLaks, do you know why must the postData be in a byte array?

Comment: @Nai: Streams hold bytes, not strings.  You can't directly send a string over a network; you need to encode it into a byte array.

Comment: You could also use a StreamWriter instead.

Comment: Right ok, thanks man! Say, don't suppose you could have a look at the follow up question to this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555334/how-do-i-need-to-read-know-in-order-to-log-into-a-site-and-perform-an-action